# import typescript definitions through tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, import, tsconfig, custom-type

Say I have the following filepath and content in my project:

`./types/foo.d.ts`

with content:

```
declare class Potato {
  constructor(options? Object);
}
```

and the following tsconfig.json

```
 {
      "compilerOptions": {
      "typeRoots": [
        "./types",
        "./node_modules/@types"
      ]
    }
```

Why does this code then throw in my app:

`const potato:Potato = ....` with:

```
Cannot find name 'Potato'.
```

Now adding the triple slash notation in the file I want explicitly does make the type issue go away, but surely this should also work through the tsconfig?

Comment: Not enough info, maybe you should import that OwnPoint?

Comment: Copy paste fail. My bad. Fixed it

Comment: import { Potato } from "./foo" ?